# the algorithm don't display the mesh

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Jupyter  in a Conda environment:

```
import igl
import meshplot as mp
import numpy as np
v, f = igl.read_triangle_mesh("./earth.ply")
k = igl.gaussian_curvature(v, f)
mp.plot(v, f, k, return_plot = True)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<meshplot.Viewer.Viewer at 0x1b53eb03fa0>
```

it is not displaying the mesh. it just outputs the location it stored in memory. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have your `meshplot.rendertype` set to `"OFFLINE"`.

If you are using this code in a jupyter notebook and want to display the mesh, then just switch `rendertype` to `"JUPYTER"`, by executing `mp.jupyter()` somewhere before your `plot()` command.

If you are running the code as a normal python program, you can export this `View` object as a HTML frame using the `View.to_html()` method. Then you can insert this frame into a html file and view it in a browser.

You can check out the source code for switching `rendertype` [here](https://github.com/skoch9/meshplot/blob/master/meshplot/plot.py#L6), how the `mp.plot` function works [here](https://github.com/skoch9/meshplot/blob/master/meshplot/plot.py#L79). The `View` class with the `to_html` method is defined [here](https://github.com/skoch9/meshplot/blob/725e4a7926a5f10888f0edd1762fecf9db751c56/meshplot/Viewer.py#L11).